# Process.StandardInput.Write is not writing to the Terminal on MacOS using .Net Core

Tags: mongodb, macos, .net-core

I'm launching a Terminal with a Mongo shell connection and sending the "show dbs" command. But it seems that after the Terminal connects it doesn't accept any commands. I'v done this on Windows 10 and Ubuntu with no problems but MacOSX High Sierra doesn't want to play nice.

Code I'm using.

```
var scriptFile = "/Users/donny/Downloads/CMStudio/mongo/mongo_script.sh";  
var appPath = "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal";

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = appPath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = scriptFile;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.Start();

process.StandardInput.Write("show dbs\n");
process.StandardInput.Flush();
```

This is the result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var scriptFile = "/Users/donny/Downloads/CMStudio/mongo/mongo_script.sh";  
var appPath = "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal";

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = appPath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = scriptFile;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError  = true;

process.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine("show dbs\n");
```